# node.js cheerio module ge

Tags: javascript, node.js, cheerio

I am using node.js and cheerio module. I want to get some data from the page.

Let's say I have this type of HTML.

```
<div class="maindiv">
     <h3 class="result-title">
                                        </span>

<a class="link-name" href="/somelink1.html" data-hovercard-id="ds54sdsd4s5d">Name1</a>


                        </h3>

     <h3 class="result-title">
                                        </span>

<a class="link-name" href="/somelink2.html" data-hovercard-id="ds54sdsd4s5d">Name2</a>



                        </h3>

     <h3 class="result-title">
                                        </span>

<a class="link-name" href="/somelink3.html" data-hovercard-id="ds54sdsd4s5d">Name3</a>


                        </h3>

</div>
```

How can I modify example bellow to get the html,link and text of the link tag.

```
request(sub_link, function (error, response, html) {

    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {

        var $ = cheerio.load(html);

        $('a.link-name').each(function () {

                            //var data = (this).html();

            var url = this.attr('href');

            console.log(url);

            links_array.push(url);

        });

    }
})
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's [what the documentation says about each](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio#each-functionindex-element-):

> Iterates over a cheerio object, executing a function for each matched
>   element. When the callback is fired, the function is fired in the
>   context of the DOM element, so this refers to the current element,
>   which is equivalent to the function parameter element. To break out of
>   the each loop early, return with false.

```
var fruits = [];

$('li').each(function(i, elem) {
  fruits[i] = $(this).text();
});

fruits.join(', ');
//=> Apple, Orange, Pear
```

So you must replace

```
var url = this.attr('href');
```

with

```
var url = $(this).attr('href');
```

You call `each` and `push` at every iterations. You should probably ask yourself whether `map` wouldn't be better.

Comment: I tried it and got this. 
TypeError: number is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/nodejs/folder/file.js:72:15)

Comment: I just tested with https://gist.github.com/rlemon/cc6c6c2de42e4be9b824 on runnable.com and it returns (logs) the hrefs correctly. Your issue likely exists elsewhere.